# Translation needed for Chinese vase

Tags: translation

Can anyone translate this for me?
[image: vase]
I need a translation for the bottom of this vase.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first we have to recognized what is written as it is not a very good writing...

I think what is written is from right to left (in simplified Chinese):
甲辰
东湖刻于
台湾
It means
these words are engraved in the year JiaChen which is a year counting by the Chinese Era, 
at the East Lake, 
in Taiwan.

Comment: Well this is just a translation, I know nothing about the history of the vase of course...

Comment: that's 東??? I took it as a personal name... it doesn't seem to make sense to have a place name before the 於... but I can't figure out what that character is supposed to be.  Also I'm seeing maybe 瑚... Ugh I hate Chinese cursive.

Comment: Ah maybe it's not. I'm not sure... Yes you are right it's a little strange to put a place before. it's engraved so more difficult to recognize. maybe we need an archaeologist here... =)

Comment: I think Master Sparkles is right. It doesn't even look like 東。 秉瑚 （a person's name) is more like it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some help from mona lisa, the reading seems to be:

> 甲辰，秉瑚（秉湖？）刻於臺*灣。

Which means

> In the Jiachen year, Binghu carved (these words) in Taiwan

"Binghu" is presumably the given name of whoever made the vase.  "Jiachen" is a permutation of the [sexagenary cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle), so it's hard to say how what exact date that corresponds to.  Most likely it refers to 1964 based on [this table](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%B2%E8%BE%B0), but if it's supposed to be older, then keep on subtracting 60 years until the answer makes sense.  (yes, that's really how it works)

* The orthography of the 臺 character is strange: is that a hint about when it might have been written, maybe? I'm kind of curious about the odd writing style...